# django-rest-framework: how to integrate URLs into existing Django application?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have an existing Django app and I want to add an API. For now I am simply trying to set up a representation of one model.

To start with, I just want to create an endpoint at `/api/1.0/county` to show all counties.

I have created a folder in the top level of my Django app called `api`, and within it I have create a `urls.py` file that contains the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from domes.models import County
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

class CountySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = County
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class CountyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = County.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountySerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'county', CountyViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Then in my root `urls.py` I have added the following:

```
import api
...
urlpatterns = ( ....
  (r'^api/1.0', include(api.urls)),
)
```

But if I try to load `/api/1.0/county` in my browser, I see `Page Not Found`, because the URL is not found in urlpatterns. Django seems to know about the following URL patterns:

^api/1.0 ^ ^$ [name='api-root']

```
^api/1.0 ^ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='api-root']
^api/1.0 ^ ^county/$ [name='county-list']
^api/1.0 ^ ^county/\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='county-list']
^api/1.0 ^ ^county/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='county-detail']
^api/1.0 ^ ^county/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='county-detail']
```

How can I get these two URL files to play nicely together?

I'd prefer to keep the API URLs in a separate file from the main app if possible. All the examples in the documentation seem to assume that django-rest-framework will be used as a standalone app, but I need to integrate it into an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a slash:

```
urlpatterns = ( ....
  (r'^api/1.0', include(api.urls)),
)
```

Add a slash at the end, or it will only match `api/1.0county/`.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend adding the slash here (in your answer) so those coming from the future better understand what you mean.